# Mathematically precise bisect cuts?

Tags: modeling, bisect

https://youtu.be/raWx4MYjq-4

^^^^^^ Example ^^^^^^^

Hi. Is it possible to make precise bisect cuts in Blender? I can only make them manually, by hand, and imprecisely.

For example, like in the video, say I wanted to bisect the object exactly on one of the 3 lines that you see there. I did it by hand in the example.

I know there are numbers in the Bisect window, but I'm not sure how to operate them. There's no "angle" or anything (which would be helpful, because in this case I could set the bisect to 72 degrees for example (but unfortunately it's not angle based)).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, that's not an easy interface to interpret, is it? First, in the top part of the window is "Plane Point" this is a point on the cutting plane. In your case, I think you should set it to the origin (0,0,0). This is also the pivot point for angle adjustments.[image]

The second part of the window is "Plane Normal." For the Y-Z plane, set it to (1,0,0).   For the X-Z plane, set it to (0, 1, 0) and for the X-Y plane, set it to (0,0,1). In the attached screenshot, it is set to (cos(72°), sin(72°), 0) and the poorly drawn white arcs show 72° for the normal referenced from the x-axis and 72° for the cutter plane referenced from the y-axis.

To further expand, lets cut out Suzanne's face at +/1 36°. I put sin(36°) and cos(36°) into a calculator and got 0.588 and 0.809 so lets see how to put those in:

[image: First Suzanne Cut]
[image: Second Suzanne Cut]

Comment: Wonderful answer! I'm sorry if it's a bit self explanatory after your answer... but, I can't seem to bisect it further for a perfect, 72 degree cut again. Could you help me with that too by any chance?

Comment: [Does this answer your question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/172424/are-you-supposed-to-only-be-able-to-bisect-once) or are you looking for some angles?

Comment: Oh no, I always select all the vertices for the mesh before I bisect. That way the bisect goes through the entire thing. I'm looking for some angles I think; one way I just did it is by rotating the mesh 120 degrees (why 120 degrees? ) and then performing the exact same cut again.

(Edit: 120 * 3 = 360... I get it, but I don't understand how to do this using bisect (without rotating the mesh)

Comment: You were asking for 72°, which makes 5 sections. Cosine and sine of 120° is -0.500 and 0.866, swapping them around and changing +/- signs gets you related angles of 30°, 60° and 150°

Comment: Very sorry, I've gotten my degrees mixed about. I've been working on this all day.

I want to cut the mesh into 3 sections (360/3 = 120, so 120 degrees) Basically, if you watch the YT video I linked, that is exactly what I want to do, but using math like you did up there.

Plugging in Cos 120 and Sin 120 and then flipping them does not cut the mesh perfectly into 1/3 of the original...

I found an easier way; make a horizontal cut, rotate the mesh 120 degrees and perform the same cut again. I basically want to do this, but without rotating the original mesh: https://youtu.be/XtTn8qIc-d0